# Alpine using localhost address

Tags: smtp, alpine-mail

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on with my setup, first there's no problem with the `imap` part as I can see my email, but when I try to send a message I get this error:

```
[Mail not sent. Sending error: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments]
```

As far as I know my `smtp` configuration is ok:

```
mail.gmx.com:465/user=user@gmx.com/ssl
```

When loking at the logs there are some entries that don't look like they're ok, it seems like alpine is using my localmachine address instead of my email address.

```
... MAIL FROM:<myhost@mylocaldomain>
... EHLO mylocaldomain
```

What can I do to change this behavior, I've been searching but can't find a parameter that to modify this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Adding the string `From: "User Name" <username@gmx.com>` at the config line  `Customized Headers` did it for me.

Otherwise I use `mail.gmx.com:587/user=username@gmx.com/tls` for the SMTP server.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the setting you're using for your outgoing SMTP server and/or IMAP server isn't quite right. Take a look at this setup example for tips on what you're doing wrong.

- [Alpine Setup](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013120623/http://support.cs.utah.edu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49:alpine-setup&catid=16:e-mail)

They show a line similar to yours as follows:

```
smtp-server=smtps.cs.utah.edu:587/tls/user=username/novalidate-cert
```

Also take a look at these setup configuration notes titled: [Notes on Configuration and Preferences](https://web.archive.org/web/20180604210210/http://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/config-notes.html), specifically this section "Server Name Syntax". This section breaks down how the SMTP server configuration lines are constructed.

There's also this guide that might be marginally useful which shows how one would setup IMAP service for use with GMail, titled: [How To Set Up Alpine With Gmail In Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20130315120229/http://people.virginia.edu/%7Ell2bf/docs/nix/alpine.html).

*excerpt*

> #### IMAP
>
> Now it's time to add Gmail accounts. Go to Main Menu => Setup =>
> Collection List => Add, and fill the IMAP information like:
>
> ```
>     Nickname  : my gmail account 
>     Server    : imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=username@gmail.com
>     Path      : 
>     View      :
> ```

And in case the above weren't enough data points, here's one more that shows setting up Alpine for use with a Zimbra server, again using IMAP, titled: [Configuring Alpine (or Pine) to read your mail](https://web.archive.org/web/20141126115812/http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/mail/configuring-alpine/).

*excerpt*

> #### SMTP server
>
> Using the arrow keys, move down to the “SMTP Server (for sending)”
> line, and press “C” for “Change Val” (or you can just hit Return).
>
> Type `zimbra.ccs.neu.edu` and hit Return, so that the line reads
>
> ```
>     SMTP Server (for sending)         = zimbra.ccs.neu.edu
> ```
>
> #### Inbox path (location of incoming mail)
>
> Then move down to the “Inbox Path” line, and change that so it reads
>
> ```
>     Inbox Path = {zimbra.ccs.neu.edu:993/ssl/user=yourusername}INBOX
> ```

And then setup Alpine so that it can see your IMAP folders:

```
Nickname  : Zimbra
Server    : zimbra.ccs.neu.edu/ssl/user=jay
Path      : 
View      :
```